# Superimpose form on image responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have to superimpose a form over an image, and it's not a problem, since with some CSS instruction it is simple. The problem is that I must do it responsively, in a way that with every monitor and resolution the positioning doesn't change and adapt itself.

This is an example: http://www.gruppofas.eu/siti-web/

Positioning the form in the green-bordered box it isn't a problem, but doing it in a way that, when viewing it in different resolutions or devices, it remains inside it, how can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: I would pay to watch someone try to fill out a form that was crammed into that tiny little box on a 320px screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries in your CSS file.
Go to your CSS and add this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { - here you add the px**** and it will resize
  .YourImage/BoxClassGoesHere* {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can also check in google for media queries.
I hope that helped you.